Mutual inductance - why is there voltage across the second coil
I am reading Hayt's "Engineering Circuit Analysis" chapter on magnetically coupled circuits.
Here is definition of mutual inductance.
$$ v_2(t) = M_{21}\frac{di_{1}(t)}{dt}$$
Here is related diagram:

Here is my question.
Changing current will generate changing magnetic field in coil 1.
Changing magnetic field will generate current in coil 2 (Faraday's Law). The current in the the second coil is not going to be changing current. Therefore, why there is voltage across the coil 2? In order for voltage to exist across coil 2, the current in coil 2 has to change. What am I missing?

Probably the M  means there is some iron between the coils. but even without, some of the B firld of coil 1 goes through coil 2 snd a changing B in coil 2  induces a current M21 gives the coupling of the two fields.


Changing magnetic field will generate current in coil 2 (Faraday's Law).

No, changing magnetic field will generate an emf (i.e. voltage) in coil 2.
$$\mathscr{E} = -N\frac{d\Phi}{dt}$$
That voltage, in turn, may cause current to flow in coil 2, but only if coil 2 is part of a closed circuit.


Changing magnetic field will generate current in coil 2 (Faraday's Law).

You are misunderstanding Faraday's Law.
Under Faraday's Law of Induction it is EMF that is "induced", not current. And it is changing magnetic flux that induces the EMF.

In order for voltage to exist across coil 2, the current in coil 2 has to change. What am I missing?

In inductors and transformers, the magnetic flux is caused by a current, but in the case of a transformer or coupled inductor that current can be in either coil. That's exactly the point of the core of the inductor, it links the flux from one coil to the other.
In a generator we can produce changing magnetic flux by mechanical motion of a permanent magnet. Then no current at all would be required to produce an EMF or voltage across a linked coil.
